How to store rsyslog client logs separately from server local messages logs
Fams. I have a rsyslog server. The logs sent from the rsyslog client are stored in a separate file, but are also entered into the local messages file on the rsyslog server. I want the client logs not to appear in the messages file on the server side. This is the rsyslog.conf on the server side:It's worked for one client，but if I have 200000 clients，I do not find any solution to handle this.
# rsyslog configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# or latest version online at http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf.html 
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
global(workDirectory="/var/lib/rsyslog")

# Use default timestamp format
module(load="builtin:omfile" Template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat")

$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514
#### MODULES ####

module(load="imuxsock"    # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
       SysSock.Use="off") # Turn off message reception via local log socket; 
              # local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
module(load="imjournal"         # provides access to the systemd journal
       StateFile="imjournal.state") # File to store the position in the journal
#module(load="imklog") # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
#module(load="immark") # provides --MARK-- message capability

$imjournalRatelimitInterval 0

$template syslog,"/var/log/remote/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
include(file="/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf" mode="optional")
#### RULES ####
if $fromhost-ip == '192.168.42.XXX' then ?syslog
& stop
if $fromhost-ip != '192.168.42.XXX' then /var/log/messages
# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
#*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

I want the logs of 200000 clients not to appear in the messages file on the server side. Is anybody can help me?
